# How does MySQL select columns ..?

Tags: mysql, sql

When there is more than one same expression present in select statement of a MySQL query does the server calculate the expression once again or reuse it ..?

**example:**

Select Column1, **upper(Column1)** as name1 from Table where **upper(Column1)** like 'ADAM%'

In the above query does **upper(Column1)** expression calculated once or twice ..?

Also, can you direct me to the document where I can find more info on this ..?

TIA

Comment: Have you checked explain plan?

Comment: Please rollback the last edit (I can't on my phone).  Some of the OP's specificity is lost by the edit.  The OP is not talking about the same columns in the SELECT clause.  OP's question is about the two `upper ()` calls.

Comment: Using an expression in a WHERE clause like that makes the query impossible to optimize with an index, so the cost of the extra evaluation in the select-list is the least of your worries!

Comment: @BillKarwin MySQL 5.7 offers expression(Virtual columns) indexes, and Postgres too, If I am not wrong. Check them out. and help me out here with this question if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have several points to answer this question.

## No Optimization

To answer your question: No, I have never read any report that MySQL "remembers" that it has already evaluated a function in the WHERE clause. It evaluates the WHERE clause and the select-list separately.

On the other hand, MySQL will evaluate deterministic constant functions (i.e. expressions that evaluate to the same constant value for every row) once, and this is a more generally useful performance improvement. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-optimization.html

## Don't Micro-Optimize

`UPPER()` is not expensive. Even running this function 1 million times still only takes 0.04 seconds, which is more than it takes to evaluate a string literal, but it's still barely noticeable.

```
mysql> select benchmark(1000000, 'adam');
+----------------------------+
| benchmark(1000000, 'adam') |
+----------------------------+
|                          0 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(1000000, upper('adam'));
+-----------------------------------+
| benchmark(1000000, upper('adam')) |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 0 |
+-----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

## Case Insensitive Searches

You don't have to use `UPPER()` at all in the query you show, if you use a case-insensitive collation (this is the default).

The `LIKE` predicate does case-insensitive comparisons by default, because of the "ci" collation.

```
mysql> show variables like '%collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci    |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci    |
+----------------------+--------------------+

mysql> select 'abc' like 'ABC';
+------------------+
| 'abc' like 'ABC' |
+------------------+
|                1 |
+------------------+
```

## Sargability

There's a much more significant cost to performance of evaluating `UPPER()` in an expression comparison in your WHERE clause.

Suppose your table has 1 million rows, but only 1000 of them match the 'ADAM%' pattern you're looking for. Using a WHERE clause like this:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT UPPER(column1) AS name1 FROM MyTable
       WHERE UPPER(column1) LIKE 'ADAM%'\G

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: MyTable
   partitions: NULL
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: column1
      key_len: 153
          ref: NULL
         rows: 735250    <-- this is an order-of-magnitude estimate
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

This cannot use an index, and therefore forces a table-scan, causing the query to read 1 million rows, and evaluate the WHERE clause expression for every row.

Whereas using a bare column:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT UPPER(column1) AS name1 FROM MyTable
       WHERE column1 LIKE 'ADAM%'\G

           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: MyTable
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: column1
          key: column1
      key_len: 153
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1000    <-- much better!
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Uses an index on Column1 (if the index exists), and examines only the matching rows. Not only can you avoid evaluating `UPPER()` 1 million times, but you avoid examining 99.9% of the rows at all!

The thing you have to keep in mind is called **sargability**. It means that MySQL can use an index to look up values, given your search expression. Putting a column inside a function call spoils sargability.

## Expression Indexes

You asked in a comment if MySQL virtual columns can help. As I have written above, this is not necessary. But for the sake of argument, here's the deal:

MySQL does not have expression indexes like [expression indexes in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) (in PostgreSQL, you include the expression in the index definition, and when you use the same expression in your WHERE clause, it knows to use the index).

MySQL has something slightly different: you define a virtual column based on an expression, and then you can index the virtual column. But you don't put the expression in the index definition.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE MyTable 
       ADD COLUMN column1_upper VARCHAR(50) AS (UPPER(column1)),
       ADD KEY (column1_upper);
```

Then when you reference the new column, it may use the index. But you don't use the expression for which the column was defined, you just use the column name bare, just like the regular rule for sargability.

Answer (score 2):

In this query:

```
Select Column1, upper(Column1) as name1
from Table
where upper(Column1) like 'ADAM%';
```

I would guess that `upper(Column1)` is evaluated twice.  Some databases have sophisticated optimizations that can find common subexpressions; I don't think MySQL does.

But, it doesn't make a difference.  `upper()` should be relatively inexpensive, compared to reading the data and compared to the `like`.  This is especially true because the query cannot use an index, so it has to do a full table scan.

MySQL does give you a way around this.  If you use `having`, then it should do the calculation only once:

```
Select Column1, upper(Column1) as name1
from Table
having upper(Column1) like 'ADAM%';
```

This is a MySQL extension.

Comment: <strong>MySQL does give you a way around this. If you use having</strong>
Where Can I find the documentation for this ..? Pls, help me here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logically the FROM & WHERE clauses are evaluated prior to the SELECT clause, and some databases (Oracle, SQL Server that I am aware of) can allocate an predicate alias to a calculated value (even case expressions) which can be reused later in the explain/execution plan. The MySQL explain plans don't reveal that level of information that I'm aware of, so I cannot be certain if MySQL is capable of this.

A further example is something "complex" such as UPPER or a case expression being repeated in both the GROUP BY and SELECT clauses, it is the SELECT clause that benefits from this because the GROUP BY is performed earlier than the SELECT. (This may be why the HAVING clause "trick" that was proposed earlier works.)

So, I think it is very useful to have an appreciation of the logical sequence of operation of clauses to make judgments on this. e.g. [A Beginner’s Guide to the True Order of SQL Operations](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations/) although I cannot definitively answer your specific question.